# Синтаксический анализ XML во время выполнения без XSD с помощью JaxB 2.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb

У меня есть xml. 
У документа, есть '**envelope**' . В '**envelope**' есть '**header**' и '**body**'. Внутри  'body' находится  'envelope' с собственным "**header**" и '**body**'  и т. д. У меня нет **xsd** для этого **xml**. Такой **xml** может иметь различную структуру.

Мне нужно получить только значения из некоторых тегов.

Я знаю, как выполнять **маршалинг** и **демаршаллинг** для Xml c использование xsd. Но в данном случае я не знаю, с чего начать.

Могу ли я получить какой-нибудь node c помощью JAXB, или же мне придется использовать все равно DOM парсер ?

Кому хороша данная тема, поясните, можно ли полностью все сделать с помощью JAXB не имея схемы. Приходят разные типы документов (тип документа спрятан в дереве xml) и в завимости от типа нужно достать определенный набор значений.

Затем вытаскивается изнутри **xml**, для которого есть **xsd** и он уже дальше анализируется с помощью **JAXB** и для него имея схему, я уже генерирую классы.

Но до этого, я должен достать значения из вложенных конвертов и их заголовков.

Каждый документ может весить **30 мб**.

Как это можно устроить ?

Какие есть варианты ?

Пожалуйста, укажите ресурсы, где это может быть использовано в качестве примера.

Answer (score 0):

Для разбора XML в JDK есть package `javax.xml.parsers`. Заглянув в него можно обнаружить класс `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder`, который предоставляет API для по-элементного разбора XML.

Comment: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder -  перегоняет документ в Dom-структуру.  А нужен не весь документ. а только часть из него, которая находится внутри, например вложенного конверта в конверт. Сотни тысяч документов поступают в приложение и каждый раз документ в 30 мб перегонять в DOM ?